# Convert a String to KeyCode (with Special Characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, char, keycode

Couldn't find any post with the right solution,

Basically what i'm trying to get, is to convert a string with special characters to KeyCode Array,

for Example: Convert `"Hello@Today"` to:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 16, 50, 116, 111, 100, 97, 121]
```

Notice the "16, 50" which is combination of Shift(16) + 2(50),

In my current code i get `(64)` for `@` **which is wrong**:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 64, 116, 111, 100, 97, 121]
```

my current function:

```
function convertToKeyCode(text) {

    var results = text.split('')
        .map(function (char) {
            return char.charCodeAt(0);
        });

    return results;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This isn't how keycodes work due to internationalisation of key layouts. For example on my UK layout keyboard SHIFT+2 gives me `"`, not `@`. Why do you want to get the separate pressed key codes instead of the output keycode?

Comment: Thanks, I need it for sending text to vmware console, using it's wmks.sendKeyCodes([char array]) method, to send the sign `@` i must seperate it first, do you have other idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a "ready-to-use" solution to convert a character to a key-code, at least in JavaScript.

Furthermore even if you implement your own conversion/mapping algorithm consider that different keyboard layouts generate characters with different key combinations.

Finally not every character code you may get with `charCodeAt` may have a corresponding key combination.